# How do I change Redux state when using Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, storybook

I have a Header component that I would like to document using Storybook. The first story is fine because I just define the initial state in the decorator(empty state). However, if I want to change the state I do not know how to do it. Here is my code:

```
const story = storiesOf("Header", module);
story.addDecorator(withRedux({}, []));
story.add("default", () => <Header />,{
    notes: "Header notes",
});
```

How can I change the initial state if I want to insert a new ".add"?

Comment: I have solved it at the end by using canned actions  from the redux addon.